# Python - Format file to list

Tags: python, list, file

I've read some questions on how to pass a file to a list, but this file it's a bit trickier as there are different data types in it, all of them represented as a string in that file.

I've managed to get a file that looks like this:

`['verb', 0, 5, 7]['noun', 9, 3, 4]`

How can I turn this into a list that looks like:

`list = [['verb', 0, 5, 7], ['noun', 9, 3, 4]]`

where `'verb'` and `'noun'` are strings and all numbers are integers.

Comment: _"I've managed to get a file that looks like this"_. Do you mean that your original file does _not_ look like that, and what we see here is the result after you do some kind of manipulation on the data first? Can we see the original file as well? It might be easier to transform the original data rather than starting with your manipulated data.

Comment: You want to take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
data = open('file.txt').read().strip('\n')
import re
lists = re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", data)
final_list = [[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i[1:-1] for i in b.split(", ")] for b in lists]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the file consists of groups enclosed in square brackets, all in one line, then probably the best idea is to replace all `][` sequences by `],[` sequences so that your data becomes valid JSON, then parse it using `json.loads`:

```
import json
with open('myfile', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline().rstrip()
list_of_lists = json.loads("[" + line.replace('][', '],[').replace("'", '"') + "]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regex` for this task. Below you can find a sketch of how to apply this technique here:

```
import re

s = "['verb', 0, 5, 7]['noun', 9, 3, 4]"

#create the regex expression
pattern = re.compile(r'\[(.*?)\]')

#store the data here
result = []

#get every item entry using the regex expression
for x in re.findall(pattern, s):
    z = x.split(",")
    #parse the data entries
    result.append([z[0].replace("'", ""), int(z[1]), int(z[2]), int(z[3])])

result

>>>[['verb', 0, 5, 7], ['noun', 9, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would open the file, then read it, store in a string and replace all "]" with "],". Then I'd `eval` (yeah I know it's evil but...) that string and would convert it to a list.

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as raw_file:
    your_str = raw_file.read()
your_str = your_str.replace('][', '],[')
your_list = list(eval(your_str))
```

If you know that the content of the file will be JSON, you can use `json.loads` instead of `eval`. In the example you gave above, you should convert `'` to `"` in order to being valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

- Identify who is storing data in this no format
- Call them
- Talk with this person about benefits to store data in an standard format. They are some available formats: csv, json, xml.
- Ask them about to receive data in this format.
- Deserialize data from file in one line library utility. Like `json.load('your_file.txt')