# While making lists of list from file in python.

Tags: python, file

I am creating a lists of list from file but i am getting a little bit wrong in my output:

```
f=open('file.txt')
line=f.readline()
a=[]
while line:
    a.append(line.strip('\n'))
    line=f.readline()
f.close()
print (a)
```

Output: `["['verb', 0, 5, 7]", "['noun', 9, 3, 4]"]`

Desired Output: `[['verb', 0, 5, 7], ['noun', 9, 3, 4]]`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156334/python-format-file-to-list/46156575#46156575

Answer (score 1):

If the file contains only literals and lists, tuples, sets, dictionaries, you can use the following approach:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('file.txt') as f:
    a = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]
print(a)
```

Here we open the file using a `with` scope, next we use *list comprehension* to parse the entire file. Finally we print it. The `literal_eval` function turns a string containing a Python literal into that literal.

Comment: Output is correct but I want modification in my code to solve this problem.beacuse i am getting this problem in my other problems.